# Cannot find a way to read APIs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I need help reading APIs with Javascript. This is what I have with PHP and works flawlessly.

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://LINK.COM');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$nickname = $obj->{'nickname'};
```

The JSON looks something like this {"nickname":"Bob"}
Unfortunately, I need to find a way to do this with Javascript.
any help would be amazing and appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
(function() {
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.addEventListener("load", function() {
 var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
 console.log(result);
 var nickname = result.nickname;
 //now continue to do something with your result
 });
 r.open("GET", "https://link.com");
 r.send(); 
 })()
```

It's not working for me

Comment: prepare an assoc array in php and then use json_encode function to convert that array into JSON. return that array to JS. :-)
And you can use jquery to make it super easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like the following

```
(function() {
   var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
   r.addEventListener("load", function() {
     var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     console.log(result);
     //now continue to do something with your result
   });
   r.open("GET", "https://LINK.COM");
   r.send(); 
})()
```

A word of caution, though; javascript is asynchronous whereas php is synchronous and blocking. It is almost certain that no result will be available if you were to try to access it after `oReq.send();`. Instead, you have to wait til the callback is executed (the anonymous function that's the second argument in the `r.addEventListener` call.

Note that there are libraries to help a little with this too and make it a little more readable. Look into jQuery or Zepto and $.ajax.

Comment: With this, how will I get nickname from the json?

Comment: The parsed json will be a JSON object, so you need to use the accessor, which is a period: `result.nickname`. I would encourage you not to try to do this by rote though.

Comment: @keithnordstorm Like this? (Check my question)

Comment: What kind of error messages are you getting? Are you doing this in a browser or on a server? I'm assuming you're not actually going to link.com, so are you running into same-origin policy issues? As I said, it seems like you're trying to do this by rote, as if it's a recipe, and that's going to be a long road. You should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) in detail but also know the tools to report problems, like where your console is.